# Multiple threads in java appending to a queue

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

I have multiple threads running which need to append to the same queue. This queue is split up into multiple variables, so effectively, I am calling a function, which appends to each variable at some position i. From http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sgDgXUUJ68&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PLBB24CFB073F1048E I was shown to add locks for each method, as shown here. http://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-multiple-locks/ . It does not seem effective to create a lock for 100,000 objects in an array. In java, let's say that I have an object which manages a large queue of objects. How can I properly synchronize addToQueue, without sacrificing performance by synchronizing the method, just the position in the floatQueue and intQueue that I am appending to?

```
class QueueManager {
    private float[] floatQueue;
    private int[] intQueue;

    private int currentQueueSize;
    private int maxQueueSize;

    QueueManager(int sizeOfQueue) {
        intQueue = new int[sizeOfQueue];
        floatQueue = new float[sizeOfQueue];

        currentQueueSize = 0;
        maxQueueSize = sizeOfQueue;
    }

    public boolean addToQueue(int a, float b) {
        if (currentQueueSize == maxQueueSize) {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            intQueue[currentQueueSize] = a;
            floatQueue[currentQueueSize] = b;

            currentQueueSize++;

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One method I though of would be to add an instance of the queue manager to each thread, and change the variables to static volatile arrays. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a BlockingQueue using offer method?

Comment: As a side note, there is unfortunately no lock free queue implementation in java

Comment: is there a way I can lock on specific positions? If so, would I have to create a lock for each positions?

Comment: You would need to update the position and the content in that position in one atomic operation to make it thread safe. That obviously requires locking of some sort - I don't think there's any way you can improve the performance over BlockingQueue implementations without using native implementations.

Comment: maybe if I make currentQueueSize a volatile type, then I can rely on that, as long as I am careful.

Comment: That doesn't work, there's no guarantee that other thread sees the update on the array without proper synchronization

Comment: What you have is definitely not thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is a non-blocking, lock-free queue implementation.  It uses compare-and-swap instructions instead of locking.

Comment: What is the speed like?

Comment: On my system that supports up to four parallel threads, it takes a little under 2.5s to add a million items apiece to the same queue.  I have the benchmarking program available here if you want to test it out yourself: https://gist.github.com/kyledewey/6399477

Answer (score 3):

Consider using BlockingQueue (java.util.concurrent) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: I want it to be non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using [Blocking Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) than reinventing the wheel. In case you are doing this for practice then you can use two locks one for *putting* and one of *getting*. Refer to the source of Blocking queue for that.

Just a side note getting concurrency right is tricky so do not use your queue in deployment application and rather rely on implementation of Java.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the parallel arrays "in synch", you need *synchronization*. It's the only way to preserve the atomicity of modifications to both arrays and their associated index.

Rather than parallel arrays, you might consider an immutable tuple object, with `final` fields for your `int` and `float`, then adding those to a `BlockingQueue` implementation, like `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

If there's a lot of churn (frequent creation and discarding of objects), `synchronized` will probably perform better than tuples. You'd need to profile them to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution I found would be to use AtomicIntegers, which is similar to locking, but runs on a much lower level than what synchronized does. Here is an updated copy of my code, with an AtomicInteger used. Please note that it still needs to be tested, but in theory, it should be sufficient.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class ThreadSafeQueueManager {
    private float[] floatQueue;
    private int[] intQueue;

    private AtomicInteger currentQueueSize;
    private int maxQueueSize;

    QueueManager(int sizeOfQueue) {
        intQueue = new int[sizeOfQueue];
        floatQueue = new float[sizeOfQueue];

        currentQueueSize = new AtomicInteger(0);
        maxQueueSize = sizeOfQueue;
    }

    public boolean addToQueue(int a, float b) {
        if (currentQueueSize.get() == maxQueueSize) {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            try {
                // Subtract one so that the 0th position can be used
                int position = currentQueueSize.incrementAndGet() - 1;
                intQueue[position] = a;
                floatQueue[positions] = b;

                return true;
            }
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { return false;}
        }
    }
}
```

Also, for reference, it is worth reading

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11234/ 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04186/

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but this is a good example of why this kind of thing is hard.  Assuming that the code is changed sufficiently so that it compiles, you will still have a data race in `addToQueue(int, float)` between checking the current queue size and adding the data to the queue.

Comment: I'm not too sure if that is true. A similar issue is found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077937/using-atomicinteger-as-a-static-shared-counter , but I just want each call of addToQueue to take only one position, since that position in the floatQueue and intQueue depend on incrementAndGet(), why is there a problem? These writes do not need to be sequential, the only requirement is that the same position in these arrays is written to only once per workload.

Comment: So if I wrap the else block with a try catch, then I am safe?

Comment: Assuming the initial test in `addToQueue(...)` is changed to `if (currentQueueSize.get() == maxQueueSize)` so the code will compile, then the following scenario could occur: 1. A thread enters the method and the test passes, but before the `int position = currentQueueSize.incrementAndGet() - 1` is executed, it is preempted.  2. The preempting thread will also pass the test, as the counter hasn't been incremented yet.  This thread completes the method.  3. Some time later the original thread from (1) is rescheduled.  If the array is now full then an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` will occur.

Comment: Why won't the try catch save me from this?

Comment: I think it will, kind of, in a workaround sort of way.  You should change the initial conditional to `>=` from `==` too.  It's also a bit ugly, in that `currentQueueSize` doesn't necessarily have the current queue size in the workaround case.  A might be to implement a method `int incrementAndGetWithLimit(AtomicInteger val, int limit)` that would only increment the counter up to a point.  You could have a look at `AtomicInteger#incrementAndGet()` for some inspiration on how this could be done http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java.html#151